# How can i change the color degree depending on value changing

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to change the color degree depend on sliding the button

i have the following screenshot

[image]

I'm trying to change the yellow color degree according to the movement of the key

How could i achieve that

Comment: Share code snippet

Comment: Here is an idea how you can start: https://medium.com/@mhstoller.it/how-i-made-a-custom-color-picker-slider-using-flutter-and-dart-e2350ec693a1